# How to append localstorage new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, local-storage

I try to append new object inside localstorage. When i try to click to store new object, its not working. It's just changed existing value inside localstorage.

Here is my code

```
addLocalStorage(e) {
  let items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('store')) || [];
  let obj = {}
  obj = {
    id: this.props.id,
    name: this.props.name,
    year: this.props.year
  };
  items.push(obj);
  localStorage.setItem('store ', JSON.stringify(items));
}
```

When I click to one of items my storage turns

```
[{id: "1", name: "lorem", year: "2016"}]
```

It's ok. But my problem is when ı clicked my other item it turns,

```
[{id: "2", name: "ipsum", year: "1990"}]
```

But i want to result

```
[{id: "1", name: "lorem", year: "2016"},{ id: "2", name: "ipsum", year: "1990" }]
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read and write different local storage items:

```
localStorage.setItem('store '
```

note the trailing space.

Comment: Omg ! You're right. Thank you so much. I think i should get to bed early tonight :)